# How can I kill (not cancel) an errant Azure Pipeline run, stage, job, or task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-yaml-pipelines

I want to know how to kill an Azure Pipeline task (or any level of execution - run, stage, job, etc.), so that I am not blocked waiting for an errant pipeline to finish executing or timeout.
For example, canceling the pipeline does not stop it immediately if a **condition** is configured incorrectly. If the condition resolves to true the task will execute even if the pipeline is cancelled.
This is really painful if your org/project only has 1 agent. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I kill (not cancel) an errant Azure Pipeline run, stage, job, or task?

For the hosted agent, we could not kill that azure pipeline directly, since we cannot directly access the running machine.

**As workaround**, we could reduce the time that the task continues to run after the job is cancelled by setting a shorter `Build job cancel timeout in minutes`:

[image]

For example, I create a pipeline with task, which will still run for 60 minutes after the job is cancelled. But if I set the value of `Build job cancel timeout in minutes` to `2` mins, the azure pipeline will be cancelled completely.

For the private agent, we could run services.msc, and look for "VSTS Agent (name of your agent)". Right-click the entry and then choose restart.

Comment: I think this is a very helpful answer because it addresses both hosted agents and self-hosted agents.  I was originally thinking of just hosted agents, but I didn't clarify in the question.  I am guessing that it would need to be a feature request to get the "Kill" ability on jobs running on a hosted agent.

Comment: Is the same option availabe for yaml pipelines as well?